# ¿Como leer los correos enviados desde gmail utilizando javamail?

Tags: java

Tengo un problema en el cual tengo que leer los correos que he enviado.
Esa parte la hago, pero solo los que he enviado por javamail y no me lee todos los que yo he enviado, solo me lee uno.

```
Properties p = new Properties();

p.setProperty("mail.store.protocol", "imaps");

Session sesion = Session.getInstance(p);

sesion.setDebug(true);

Store store = sesion.getStore();

store.connect("imap.gmail.com", "jhonnyalcadio@gmail.com", "miclavedegmail");

Folder folder = store.getFolder("[Gmail]/Enviados");

folder.open(Folder.READ_ONLY);

mensajes = folder.getMessages();

Message m = folder.getMessage(folder.getMessageCount());

Address[] in = m.getFrom();

for (Address address : in) {
      System.out.println("Email: "+address.toString()+"\n");
}

Multipart mp = (Multipart) m.getContent();

BodyPart bp = mp.getBodyPart(0);

System.out.println("Bcc User Name: "+InternetAddress.toString(m.getRecipients(Message.RecipientType.BCC)));
System.out.println("SENT DATE: "+m.getSentDate());
System.out.println("SUBJECT: "+m.getSubject());
System.out.println("Content: "+bp.getContent());
```

Ahí está ingresando a mi bandeja de enviados pero como dije, solo me lee un solo correo.

Comment: Ten cuidado con la ortografía cuando escribas `e` es equivalente a `y`, `he` es del verbo haber usado para crear ciertos tiempos verbales ;)

Comment: Buen apunte. Después de punto también mayusculas siempre! En todos los idiomas.

Answer (score 2):

Deberías hacer un bucle sobre los mensajes obtenidos:

```
mensajes = folder.getMessages();

for (Message m : mensajes) {

    Address[] in = m.getFrom();

    for (Address address : in) {
        System.out.println("Email: "+address.toString()+"\n");
    }

    Multipart mp = (Multipart) m.getContent();

    BodyPart bp = mp.getBodyPart(0);

    System.out.println("Bcc User Name: "+InternetAddress.toString(m.getRecipients(Message.RecipientType.BCC)));
    System.out.println("SENT DATE: "+m.getSentDate());
    System.out.println("SUBJECT: "+m.getSubject());
    System.out.println("Content: "+bp.getContent());

}
```

Eso si los obtienes todos de una vez y luego los procesas. También podrías ir obteniendo cada uno y procesandolo:

```
for(int i = 0; i < folder.getMessageCount(); i++) {
    Message m = folder.getMessage(i);

    // Procesar el mensaje.
}
```

Si te fijas en la documentación de [getMessages()](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/mail/Folder.html#getMessages()), este devuelve un array con todos los mensajes. De ahí que tengas que recorrerlo para ir mostrándolos. Y como sabes cuantos son, la mejor estructura para recorrer es un bucle `for`.